# jquery .hover, then .click to animate trouble

Tags: jquery, click, hover, if-statement

Update: I have consolidated my code and tried to add the if/else statement. I still haven't figured out how to get on click  ignore the mouseenter/mouseleave functions

```
$('#storybtn').on({
mouseenter:function(){
    $('#story')
        .stop()
        .animate({top:'405px'},'slow');
},
mouseleave:function(){
    $('#story')
        .stop()
        .animate({top:'435px'},'slow');
},
click:function(){
    var position = $('#story').css('top');
    if (position>'10px'){
    $('#story')
        .stop()
        .animate({top:'10px'},'slow');
        }
    else (position='10px'){
    $('#story')
        .stop()
        .animate({top:'435px'},'slow');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a example fiddle for you:

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a88qg/)

To avoid the mouseleave animation after a click happend I added a class click to the #story and a if/else case to check for it or remove it after mouseleave:

```
 $('#storybtn').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $('#story')
                .stop()
                .animate({top: '405px'}, 'slow');
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            if (!$('#story').hasClass('clicked')) {
            $('#story')
                .stop()
                .animate({top: '435px'}, 'slow');
            } else {
                $('#story').removeClass('clicked')
            }
        },
        click: function () {
            var position = $('#story').css('top');
            if (position > '10px') {
                $('#story')
                    .addClass('clicked')
                    .stop()
                    .animate({top: '10px'}, 'slow');
            } else if (position === '10px') {
                $('#story')
                    .addClass('clicked')
                    .stop()
                    .animate({top: '435px'}, 'slow');
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your syntax for `.hover()` is deprecated with newer versions of jQuery. Second, you need to stop the other animations before activating your new one, otherwise it will just queue it until the previous animations finish. Try this:

```
$('#storybtn').on({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $('#story')
            .stop()
            .animate({top:'405px'},'slow');
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
        $('#story')
            .stop()
            .animate({top:'435px'},'slow');
    },
    click:function(){
        $('#story')
            .stop()
            .animate({top:'10px'},'slow');
    }
});
```

This makes use of the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler, which is what `.click()` and `.hover()` are shorthand for. By using the real thing, you can consolidate your code.

Comment: The .on works better but when I click and the mouse is left behind and breaks the div plane it rolls back automatically.